# When did Arataka Reigen increase his psychic powers?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

At the begining of the anime series, Arataka Reigen didnt have any psychic powers. Then, at the end of season 1, after being lent Mob's powers, according to him, "he could only see Dimple". And now at the begining of season 3 of the anime, he can see other spirits.

When did Arataka Reigen increase his psychic powers?