# Can Arataka Reigen exorcise spirits now?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

In season 3 episode 1 of the anime, Arataka Reigen tells Mob that he lets them do the work of exorcising the spirit because "he's too powerful" or something like that. Arataka was only a bluff, but now he not only can see Dimple but other spirits, so he increased his powers.

Can Arataka Reigen exorcise spirits now or he is still bluffing?

Comment: Aren't this and [your other recent question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/67310/49) addressed by the same answer?